# T-SQL UPDATE statement affects more records than select statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-update

The following is driving me nuts, please help me!

As a check before running an UPDATE statement (T-SQL; SQL Server 2012) I run:

```
select  * 
from Treatment_Day42 
where td42pinit = 'J M' and td42pid = 'ADA';
```

and I get 1 row returned, as I expect.

However, running

```
update Treatment_Day42 set td42pid = 'ADA252' 
where td42pinit = 'J M' and td42pid = 'ADA';
```

affects four records, not one as in the select statement with the exact same WHERE clause. I get the row returned by the select plus 3 other rows where td42pid = ADA458, ADA671 and ADA658.

Why is the UPDATE affecting more rows than I intend it to?

Thanks.

Clemens

Comment: Is it a table or a view your updating to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trigger on the table could do this. Have you checked for an existing trigger?

Comment: Thanks! Disabling the trigger on this table solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, and then I checked, I had implemented a `TRIGGER` on `myTable`.

**To check, if you having any trigger on your `table` or not, just try it:**

```
EXEC sp_helptrigger yourTableName;
```

Answer (score 0):

If its not a trigger it could also be on update cascade. This however less common than triggers so I would check triggers first. If not check out your table and the column that you are updating.

Answer (score 0):

You must be having a trigger on your table which must be affecting more rows. You can check for trigger on a table by using

```
EXEC sp_helptrigger 'tablename';
```

For more options on sp_helptrigger, you can visit the below MSDN link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189836.aspx

Comment: Yes, I do have triggers on that, and other tables, to audit changes to the tables. Removing the trigger in order for my UPDATE script to work seems odd as any changes won't be recorded in the audit trail, as per my trigger. Why does the trigger cause this behavior? How could I write it so that it does not cause this situation? Thanks