# Sybase ASE- Can an UPDATE statement affect more records than the results window shows?

Tags: sql, sql-update, sap-ase

I'm part of a small US business intelligence team, in a global firm, that consists of power users on the business side with `write`/`drop`/`create` permission on a specific database within `Sybase ASE`. Before recently, we had a contractor in the office with us taking on the more mundane aspects of our daily reporting/processing. We were essentially forced to move to a couple full time lower level employees located in India who have worked out great for the most part. Recently, one of them has committed a sloppy `UPDATE` statement not once but twice within the last 2 weeks which has corrupted data going back 12 years. The employee claims that the update statement was not sloppy and the results window showed the desired amount of updated records (2, not 30,000+). In a normal firm, we could check the log file but the DBA responsibilities were outsourced to a terrible service providing firm and they can't provide the log files in a pin pointed manner (between 3 and 8am on a given day).

I want to believe the employee but it just doesn't make any sense. My question is: without being able to reference the log files, is there any possibility of a system bug where an `UPDATE` statement might update more records than the results window would show? Maybe the distance from the Indian employees PC to the server in the US could cause something?

There are no triggers on this table as was suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24141599/t-sql-update-statement-affects-more-records-than-select-statement).

Thanks-

Comment: define 'results window'; I work almost entirely via command line (`isql`) so if I've got 30K lines of output ... I'm gonna get 30K lines of output; then again, an `UPDATE` statement (99.9% of the time) is not going to generate 30K lines of output ... instead, it will usually generate 1 line of output => a message that says something like '30,xxx rows affected' (but even this will be based on the client/front-end through which you're running the `UPDATE`); have you asked for the actual `UPDATE` stmt that was issued?

Comment: if your ASE instance has MDA tables configured, and enough memory set aside to capture `monSysStatement` data, you could, if you query `monSysStatement` shortly after the `UPDATE` is performed, capture the stats for the `UPDATE` stmt (including number of affected rows); alternatively, ask the DBA if MDA data is being captured in a respository (eg, `asemon`) and if so, how you can query the historical data from `monSysStatement`; and no, distance isn't going to affect how many rows are touched by an `UPDATE` stmt; just curious, has the DBA enabled command auditing?

Comment: @markp We use RapidSQL IDE although the output seen in our IDE would also come through in command line isql. Sadly, we don't have access to the master db so I can't query that table. We've asked the employee what SQL she ran but it seems like they adjusted it correctly before sending over to us.